# How to find element with selenium on python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.skysports.com/champions-league-fixtures')
time.sleep(7) #So page loads completely
teamnames = browser.find_element_by_tag("span")
print(teamnames.text)
```

seems find_element attribute is changed on selenium :/
i also want to find all <img on another local website ( images url  ) , appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `teamnames = browser.find_element_by_tag("span")`

with `teamnames = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("span")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find **elements** instead of **element**, because in DOM Tags are always considered multiple.

Example:

```html
browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')
```

Also, not that it will return a list of elements you need to traverse to access properties further.

Answer (score 0):

Seems selenium made some changes in new version:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('url')
browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='')
```

You can also use : By.ID - By.NAME - By.XPATH - By.LINK_TEXT - By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT - By.TAG_NAME - By.CLASS_NAME - By.CSS_SELECTOR

I used these in Python 3.10 and now its working just fine